# I want to convert a CIImage to UIImage but failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, ciimage, cvpixelbuffer

I have a CIImage with format `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange`(`YCC420f` or `N12`), now I want to see what the image looks like, so I convert it to UIImage use this method:

```
CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:new_buffer];

CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef videoImage = [temporaryContext
                          createCGImage:ciImage
                               fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                        CVPixelBufferGetWidth(new_buffer),
                                        CVPixelBufferGetHeight(new_buffer))];

UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:videoImage];
```

It's works fine when the image's format is `BGRA`, but not for `NV12`, error message in console:

```
Render failed because a pixel format YCC420f is not supported.
```

Btw, the ciimage comes from a CVPixelBufferRef, and the CVPixelBufferRef comes from an address of a GL texture.

Now, what should I do?

Comment: use UIImage *uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:ciImage]; not imageWithCGImage:

Comment: @Yuri same problem. And CIImage->CGImageRef->UIImage is better, imageWithCIImage may return `nil` with no error message sometimes.

Comment: Works form ios 7 : UIImage *uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:ciImage];

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple line of code (Available from IOS 5.0)

UIImage *uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:ciImage];